# Running PhantomJS as a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, seo, phantomjs

I'm looking into using PhantomJS to generate static html from a dynamic AngularJS app that can be indexed by google. What I want to do is to start a PhantomJS server that sits behind a proxy and gets the `?escaped_fragment` requests. PhantomJS appears to be (mainly) a command line tool (I have read the FAQ explaining why it's not a regular node module), and although I have found a couple of nodejs bridges for it, they appear to be a little bit unreliable.

Therefore, I'm looking into running PhantomJS with an embedded HTTP server. I have seen some examples of a built in webserver in PhantomJS, but I'm not sure if it's meant to be used this way? If not, is it possible to have PhantomJS use regular node modules, like e.g. expressjs, so I can use the PhantomJS runtime to also host a simple webserver?

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem right now. Did you eventually manage to run `PhantomJS` to make your `AngularJS` app. searchable ? Would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The bridge node-phantom isn't unreliable (phantom-node is unreliable, and overcomplicated, so don't use that one).

Phantom itself can sometimes be a bit unreliable, but it tends to be with specific web sites.

I'm not convinced Phantom is the right solution for you though - you might want to check out JSDom instead, and just have your code run in-process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will JSDom be able to run the angularjs app with full javascript support, ajax and everything?

Comment: I'm not too convinced about JSDom. From what I've gathered so far, it appears to not handle ajax requests. I'll check out the node-phantom bridge though.